# Change the file configuration of Spring framework and java to JSON

Tags: java, spring

the problem file XML configurations spring framework and JAVA can not change ? while in others they rather use now JSON ...

Comment: What is your question ? Is this about the spring beans configuration ?

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  How does this fail?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have a spring configuration using annotation.  Follow link :
https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/

And have JSON from java class. Link:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/